# In Swift and ARKit is it possible to create a 2D object with an non-smooth edge programmatically?

Tags: swift, arkit

This may be a silly question so be kind. I've been messing around with ARKit and I'm able to create objects programmatically like circles, squares, rectangles, etc. I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically create a 2-dimensional object that has an unorthodox border. I'm hoping to create something like this:

[image]

Is this possible? It doesn't have to be exactly like what I'm showing here. I do like the bumps, they can all be more uniform if that's easier. I'd just like to create something that's not so... default-looking.

Thanks in advance!